# Application Verifier causes hooked x64 application with EasyHook to crash

Tags: c++, windows, easyhook

Currently there is the next problem when EasyHook is used and Application Verifier is enabled.
If appverifier disabled application works, but with application verifier enabled target application crashes. And its rather critical to have application verifier working. So is there any ideas what can be done to have hooks and appverifier running?

Simplest x64 program I managed to create also crashes when hooks are used.
I created a native dll with one exported function

original.dll: main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall OriginalFunction() {
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

And the main program holds next:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <release-2.7/Public/easyhook.h>

typedef void (__stdcall *OriginalFunctionFunc)();

OriginalFunctionFunc OriginalFunction;

void __stdcall OriginalFunctionHook() {
    std::cout << "No hello world available" << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(_T("original.dll"));
    OriginalFunction = (OriginalFunctionFunc)GetProcAddress(hModule, "OriginalFunction");
    OriginalFunction();

    HOOK_TRACE_INFO handle;
    memset(&handle, 0, sizeof(handle));
    NTSTATUS status = LhInstallHook(OriginalFunction, OriginalFunctionHook, (void*)0, &handle);

    if (NT_ERROR(status)) {
        std::cout << "Can't install hook" << std::endl;
    }
    ULONG p[] = {0};
    LhSetExclusiveACL(p, 0, &handle);

    OriginalFunction();

    return 0;
}
```

Application verifier is tuned with default options for Basics tests.
WinDbg output is:

```
(19d0.1298): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
ntdll!RtlCaptureContext+0x86:
00000000`772a08c5 0fae8100010000  fxsave  [rcx+100h]    ds:00000000`001aed68=e9
0:000> kb
RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
00000000`7725b219 : 000007ff`fffde000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlCaptureContext+0x86
00000000`7725b559 : 00000000`001af208 00000000`00000025 00000000`001afea0 00000000`00000005 : ntdll!RtlpWalkFrameChain+0x49
00000000`7725b4ea : 00000000`001ab000 000007fe`f79e6740 00000000`001afea0 00000000`001afba0 : ntdll!RtlWalkFrameChain+0x2d
00000000`773170e4 : 00000000`001b0000 00000000`099b0000 00000000`00000c00 00000000`0000027f : ntdll!RtlCaptureStackBackTrace+0x4a
00000000`773171ab : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlStdLogStackTrace+0x24
000007fe`f79e6d84 : 00000000`00001000 00000000`099b1000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlLogStackTrace+0x1b
000007fe`f79e8513 : 00000000`00001000 00000000`099b1000 00000000`099b1000 00000000`00000c00 : verifier!AVrfpDphPlaceOnBusyList+0x38
00000000`77327041 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`01001002 00000000`01001002 00000000`03d48548 : verifier!AVrfDebugPageHeapAllocate+0x26f
00000000`772eb5aa : 00000000`099b0000 00000000`001af4e8 00000000`099b0000 00000000`77392dd0 : ntdll!RtlDebugAllocateHeap+0x31
00000000`772a34d8 : 00000000`099b0000 00000000`01001002 00000000`00000c00 00000000`00000000 : ntdll! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x18b42
000007fe`f7a659fa : 00000000`00000004 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 000007fe`f1ae9487 : ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0x16c
000007fe`f80efd34 : 000007fe`f811d440 000007fe`f811c440 00000000`00000000 000007fe`f811d440 : vfbasics!AVrfpRtlAllocateHeap+0xee
000007fe`faeb030c : 000007fe`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : EasyHook64!LhBarrierIntro+0x154 [d:\projects\easy_hook\release-2.7\drivershared\localhook\barrier.c @ 787]
000007fe`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x7fe`faeb030c
00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x7fe`00000000
```

OS: Windows 7 x64
Built with VS 2010
AppVerifier 4.1.1078

I posted similar question here https://easyhook.codeplex.com/discussions/542316 but unfortunately without any results.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am currently working on reversing on how does the Application Verifier sets its hooks (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/archive/blogs/reiley/a-debugging-approach-to-application-verifier) but it's very likely that the hooks from easyHook and from the Application Verifier are "colliding", causing the bug